# Converting words/numbers to Discord "letter/number emojis"

Tags: python, beginner, strings, tkinter

I am a beginner to Python (and programming overall) and I decided that it would be funny if I wrote a program that could convert Letters/Numbers to these 
"Letter Emojis" in Discord.
It works but I am quite unsure if this is the best way to do it.
There are also some bugs caused by adding spaces before actually typing Letters/Numbers.
I commented it as precisely as I could to make the Code as understandable as possible

````py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()


# defines the funtion click which gets called when the submitButton1 is pressed
def click():
    # makes sure the list is empty in case the user presses the button again to convert something new
    result.clear()
    # saves the text which is entered in the textentry box, this later gets converted to "Discord Letters"
    entered_text=textentry.get()
    # deletes the output box in case the user presses the button again to convert something new
    output.delete(1.0, END)
    # the function to convert a String to "Discord Letters"
    discord(entered_text)
    # loop which gets the length of the string typed in the textentry box and then outputs it to the output textbox
    for i in range(len(entered_text)):
        output.insert(END, result[i])


# A List in which the converted Letters are stored it's later used to output the converted Letters in a Textbox
result = []


# the function to convert a String to "Discord Letters"
def discord(word):
    # List of numbers from 0-9 , is used to check the string for numbers and then convert them
    # to "Discord Digits" since they have a different syntax in discord than Letters
    chars = set('0123456789')
    s = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
         'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
    # In case the User enters spaces they get removed since they just cause trouble
    word = word.replace(" ", "")
    word = word.lower()
    w = word
    for i in range(len(w)):
        # checks if the string has a number and outputs accordingly
        if any((c in chars) for c in w[i]):
            list_one = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", ]
            result.append(':' + list_one[int(w[i])] + ":" + " ")
        # checks if the string has letter and outputs accordingly (might be unnecessary)
        elif any((c in s) for c in w[i]):
            result.append(':regional_indicator_' + w[i] + ":" + " ")
        else:
            # In case the user inputs something wrong
            print("False Input")


root.title("Discord Letter Converter")
# TextInput
textentry = Entry(root, width=20, bg="white")
textentry.pack()
# submitButton
submitButton1 = Button(root, text="Submit", width=6, command=click)#
submitButton1.pack()
# TextOutput
output = Text(root, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background="white")
output.pack()
root.mainloop()
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about these "Discord letters"

**Code organisation**

You could reorganise your code to make units easier to use independently.

The easiest thing to do it to re-write the `discord` function so that it returns a value instead of updating a global variable.

Another thing to do is to put all the Tkinter logic into a function. Usually, that function actually doing things would be put [behind an `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

We'd have

```
# the function to convert a String to "Discord Letters"
def convert_to_discord_letters(word):
    # A List in which the converted Letters are stored it's later used to output the converted Letters in a Textbox
    result = []
    # List of numbers from 0-9 , is used to check the string for numbers and then convert them
    # to "Discord Digits" since they have a different syntax in discord than Letters
    chars = set('0123456789')
    s = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
         'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
    # In case the User enters spaces they get removed since they just cause trouble
    word = word.replace(" ", "")
    word = word.lower()
    w = word
    for i in range(len(w)):
        # checks if the string has a number and outputs accordingly
        if any((c in chars) for c in w[i]):
            list_one = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", ]
            result.append(':' + list_one[int(w[i])] + ":" + " ")
        # checks if the string has letter and outputs accordingly (might be unnecessary)
        elif any((c in s) for c in w[i]):
            result.append(':regional_indicator_' + w[i] + ":" + " ")
        else:
            # In case the user inputs something wrong
            print("False Input")
    # print(result)
    return result


# defines the funtion click which gets called when the submitButton1 is pressed
def click():
    # saves the text which is entered in the textentry box, this later gets converted to "Discord Letters"
    entered_text=textentry.get()
    # deletes the output box in case the user presses the button again to convert something new
    output.delete(1.0, END)
    # the function to convert a String to "Discord Letters"
    result = convert_to_discord_letters(entered_text)
    # loop which gets the length of the string typed in the textentry box and then outputs it to the output textbox
    for i in range(len(entered_text)):
        output.insert(END, result[i])


def tkinter_discord_letter_converter():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Discord Letter Converter")
    # TextInput
    textentry = Entry(root, width=20, bg="white")
    textentry.pack()
    # submitButton
    submitButton1 = Button(root, text="Submit", width=6, command=click)#
    submitButton1.pack()
    # TextOutput
    output = Text(root, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background="white")
    output.pack()
    root.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    tkinter_discord_letter_converter()
```

Note: I do not have tested this because I do not have Tkinter but I've tested parts of your code because I have...

**Unit Tests**

Now that the code is reorganised, we can easily write small tests for the `discord` function that I've renamed `test_convert_to_discord_letters`

```
def test_convert_to_discord_letters():
    """Test function convert_to_discord_letters."""
    # TODO: This could/should use a proper unit-test framework
    # Empty case
    assert convert_to_discord_letters("") == []
    # Whitespace
    assert convert_to_discord_letters(" ") == []
    # Special characters
    assert convert_to_discord_letters("#~&$£()[]") == []
    # Lowercase letters
    assert convert_to_discord_letters("abcz") == [':regional_indicator_a: ', ':regional_indicator_b: ', ':regional_indicator_c: ', ':regional_indicator_z: ']
    # Uppercase letters
    assert convert_to_discord_letters("ABCZ") == [':regional_indicator_a: ', ':regional_indicator_b: ', ':regional_indicator_c: ', ':regional_indicator_z: ']
    # Digits
    assert convert_to_discord_letters("42") == [':four: ', ':two: ']
    # Mix
    assert convert_to_discord_letters("Bar -_- 9") == [':regional_indicator_b: ', ':regional_indicator_a: ', ':regional_indicator_r: ', ':nine: ']
```

**Improving `test_convert_to_discord_letters`**

Now that we have unit-tests for the function, we can more safely try to improve it without breaking its behavior.

**Loop like a native**

I highly recommend [Ned Batchelder's talk "Loop like a native"](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html) about iterators. One of the most simple take away is that whenever you're doing range(len(iterabme)), you can probably do things in a better way: more concise, clearer and more efficient.

In your case, this gives:

```
    for char in w:
        # checks if the string has a number and outputs accordingly
        if any((c in chars) for c in char):
            list_one = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", ]
            result.append(':' + list_one[int(char)] + ":" + " ")
        # checks if the string has letter and outputs accordingly (might be unnecessary)
        elif any((c in s) for c in char):
            result.append(':regional_indicator_' + char + ":" + " ")
        else:
            # In case the user inputs something wrong
            pass # print("False Input")
```

Then, a few things seem more obvious:

- we don't really need the `w` variable. Also, various re-assignment of `word` are not required
- the variations of `any((c in XXX) for c in char)` look weird once we realise that `char` is a single character. We could write this: `if char in XXX`
- the variable `chars` would be better named `digits` while `s` would be better named `letters`

At this stage, we have

```
# the function to convert a String to "Discord Letters"
def convert_to_discord_letters(word):
    # A List in which the converted Letters are stored it's later used to output the converted Letters in a Textbox
    # List of numbers from 0-9 , is used to check the string for numbers and then convert them
    # to "Discord Digits" since they have a different syntax in discord than Letters
    digits = set('0123456789')
    letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
    result = []
    for char in word.replace(" ", "").lower():
        # checks if the string has a number and outputs accordingly
        if char in digits:
            list_one = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", ]
            result.append(':' + list_one[int(char)] + ":" + " ")
        # checks if the string has letter and outputs accordingly (might be unnecessary)
        elif char in letters:
            result.append(':regional_indicator_' + char + ":" + " ")
        else:
            # In case the user inputs something wrong
            pass # print("False Input")
    # print(result)
    return result
```

**Definitions of data used**

For letters, you could use `ascii_lowercase` from `string` module:

```
import string
...
    letters = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

For digits, you define a set and a list, convert the value to integer to get the string at the relevant index. It seems like the best data structure to use would be a single dictionnary mapping digits to strings.

```
    digits = {"0": "zero", "1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three", "4": "four", "5": "five", "6": "six", "7": "seven", "8": "eight", "9": "nine"}
```

**Useless concatenations of literal string**

`":" + " "` can be written `": "`.

At this stage, we have:

```
# the function to convert a String to "Discord Letters"
def convert_to_discord_letters(word):
    # A List in which the converted Letters are stored it's later used to output the converted Letters in a Textbox
    # List of numbers from 0-9 , is used to check the string for numbers and then convert them
    # to "Discord Digits" since they have a different syntax in discord than Letters
    digits = {"0": "zero", "1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three", "4": "four", "5": "five", "6": "six", "7": "seven", "8": "eight", "9": "nine"}
    letters = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
    result = []
    for char in word.replace(" ", "").lower():
        # checks if the string has a number and outputs accordingly
        if char in digits:
            result.append(':' + digits[char] + ": ")
        # checks if the string has letter and outputs accordingly (might be unnecessary)
        elif char in letters:
            result.append(':regional_indicator_' + char + ": ")
        else:
            # In case the user inputs something wrong
            pass # print("False Input")
    print(result)
    return result
```

And we realise that most comments are not required anymore because the code is much clearer. On the other hand, we could add a proper docstring.

```
def convert_to_discord_letters(word):
    """Convert a string into a list of strings corresponding to "Discord Letters"."""
    digits = {"0": "zero", "1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three", "4": "four", "5": "five", "6": "six", "7": "seven", "8": "eight", "9": "nine"}
    letters = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
    result = []
    for char in word.replace(" ", "").lower():
        if char in digits:
            result.append(':' + digits[char] + ": ")
        elif char in letters:
            result.append(':regional_indicator_' + char + ": ")
        else:
            pass # TODO: I'll let you decide how to handle other cases
    return result
```

**Removing the useless logic**

It is now clearer that the `.replace(" ", "")` logic removes whitespace which would have no effect anyway (as we'd end up in the non-handled case).
You can remove this.

**More**

I suspect the `click` function could benefit from the same ideas but it can't test it at the moment.

Also, the code seems to assume that `entered_text` and `result` will have the same length which may not be the case for non-handled characters.